# Django Documentation 'ManyToManyField'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, manytomanyfield

can anyone please tell how did they get all the articles of a particular publication
as shown the documentation the query is

```
>>>p2.article_set.all()
```

but what is article_set in the query

for model reference look into the documentation below is the link

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#

and the query is also present the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The define a model with a `ManyToManyField` from `Article` to `Publication`:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['headline']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

If you add such relation, Django will automatically add a relation in the *opposite* direction as well. So to access the `Article`s froma `Publication`. The name of this relation is specified by the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name).

Here of course we did not specify a value for the `related_name=…` parameter. In that case, it defaults to the `modelname_set`, so the name of the model in *lowercase*, followed by a `…_set` suffix. In this case thus `article_set`.

You thus can access the related `Article`s for a `Publication` with `mypublication.article_set.all()`. For this it looks at the relation in reverse.